# An error occurred while exporting the onnx model

Tags: pytorch, typeerror, onnx

Here is the model:[SMSR](https://github.com/The-Learning-And-Vision-Atelier-LAVA/SMSR)

When I try to export the onnx model using torch.onnx.export(self.model, lr, onnx_save_path, verbose=True), the following error occurs:

**TyperError: state_dict() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given**

My torch version is: 1.1.0

So, what should I do?

Thank U all!!!

Answer (score 0):

Torch version is quite old, your code would run in version `1.12`